# Hyperledger FabCar Network issue via Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

While reproducing steps from an interesting tutorial found online - [Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 Tutorial - FabCar Sample Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2moCQeHCx-g), I have installed all `Hyperledger Fabric` binaries via the `Curl` command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

From the `Command Prompt` window one can see that, the scripts are run correctly leading to the pull of `hyperledger-docker images`.

[image: Fabric Images]

However, while launching the `network` from Visual Studio Code through the execution of

`./startFabric.sh javascript` from the `fabcar` sub-directory, one ends up with `Fabric Images` issues, which seems paradoxical.
[image: Fabric_Images_Issues]

A similar issue has been encountered, while attempting to bring up the `network` via the command

```
./network.sh up
```

from the `test-network` sub-directory too.

Thus, any relevant feedback would indeed be appreciated, given an absence of rationale to justify this matter.

**[EDIT]**

As a matter of fact, a synchronization issue might have caused the previously reported issue, since `fabric-samples` `v.1.4.9` is not found from `Curl` `command` documented online. Thus the script automatically installs the latest `Fabric binaries` `2.x`.

To rule out this issue, I have re-executed the `Curl` `command` by specifying the version `1.4.4` instead.
Therefore I can confirm, that the `test-network` sub-directory is not part of the `Fabric` `binaries` pertaining to the version `1.4x`.
Furthermore, before the installation of this binaries, I had removed all `containers`, and related `images`, yielding to:

[image: docker_images]

Back to the `fabcar` sub-directory, running:
`./startFabric.sh javascript` has still led to the following `network` issue :

[image: binary_file_issue]

What strikes me the most is:

- firstly, that `configtxlator` can be found on my `C:\Users\...\Documents\test4\fabric-samples\bin` as opposed to the path highlighted on the `command window`.
- secondly, I do not see the matter of version's incompatibility by scrutinizing `byfn.sh`:

[image: docker_version_issue]

Eventually, the manual amendment of `IMAGETAG` has not improved the situation.

Best

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the different version.

In `hyperledger/fabric-samples`, the `test-network` does not exist in version `1.4`. In other words, you are running the code for the `master` version of `fabric-samples` (currently the version `2.x` version). Since you're running the `1.4` tutorial, run the commands based on the `1.4` documentation and code.

- [fabric/docs/release-1.4](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html)
- [fabric/samples/release-1.4](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4)

---

[NOTE] It is also very likely that the different version binary has been installed. In the fabric document, the version can be specified and downloaded, so to download the binary of the corresponding version, you need to execute the command including the input parameter (version) below.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s - 1.4.9 1.4.9 0.4.21
```

---

[EDIT - 1]
Prior to the explanation, in 1.4.x, `first-network/byfn.sh` exists, not `test-network/network.sh`. Change the branch of your `fabric-samples` to release-1.4.
Do not run 2.x code while doing the 1.4 tutorial.

`./byfn.sh` basically executes the image tag as `latest`. That is, if you have pulled the `2.`x version of the image, even if you proceed to `1.4.x`, it will run as `2.x`.

```
cd fabric-samples
git checkout release-1.4
```

There are two ways.

1. tag the `latest` with `1.4.x` image
   Untag all hyperledger `latest` image tags, and tag `1.4.x` images as `latest`.
   (In fact, the easiest way is to delete both the 2.x and 1.4.x images and execute the command again.)
2. Or edit in `byfn.sh`
   There is a part to set `IMAGE_TAG` in `byfn.sh`.

- byfn.sh

```sh
# default image tag
# IMAGETAG="latest"
IMAGETAG="1.4.9"
```

Make sure the value of that part matches your `1.4.x` version

---

[EDIT - 2]
For binary I don't know where and how you built it. However, you can easily build it on the fabric github.

1. make binaries

```sh
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
git clone http://github.com/hyperledger/fabric
cd fabric
git checkout release-1.4
make native
```

> - Makefile
>   native - ensures all native binaries are available
>   configtxgen - builds a native configtxgen binary
>   configtxlator - builds a native configtxlator binary
>   cryptogen  -  builds a native cryptogen binary
>   idemixgen  -  builds a native idemixgen binary
>   peer - builds a native fabric peer binary
>   orderer - builds a native fabric orderer binary

2. Path setting

```sh
mv $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/bin/* <your_bin_path>

# in my case
# mv $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/bin/* usr/local/bin
```

or

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/bin
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, please note that whether I use your ```curl``` command or ```curl -sSL ... | bash -s -- 1.4.9 1.4.9 0.4.21``` (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html) to point to ```v1.4```, the ```test-network``` does exist for some reasons, leading to the same ```network``` issue as highlighted in the picture. Best Wishes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments., and I've amended the ```post``` accordingly since the nub of the matter may lie in a synchronization issue between the ```Fabric``` ```binaries``` and related ```Docker``` images.

Comment: Installing binaries and registering paths is very basic, so I've edited them further in the answer. Also, new questions should be created according to the guidelines in StackOverflow, not modifying the question. (The question is not good if it is broad or contains multiple questions.)

Comment: I agree that installing ```binaries``` and ```registering``` ```paths``` are rudimentary tasks. Your latest point ```1.``` could even be performed the single ```curl  command``` documented on the ```H. Fabric``` website. ```2.``` could be performed by editing the environment variable. To minimize any synchronization issue, v.2X has been downloaded downloaded and related binaries automatically installed, since the curl performs altogether 4 documented steps. The purpose of editing was to provide additional details to the network issue encountered instead of duplicating the same problem.

Comment: My issue was mainly tributary on the mixed ```Docker containers``` downloaded (for different ```Fabric``` versions) and not cleared/removed, and your suggestions finally raised that awareness. Thus, thank you for all your input(s). Best.